# Condition for existence of unique solution for logistic regression

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Given the problem of maximization of log-likelihood in logistic regression.

$log(P(D)) = \sum_{n = 1}^
N
y_{n}log(σ(w^{T}
x_{n})) + (1 − y_{n})log(1 − σ(w^{T}
x_{n}))$

Where $x_{n}$ are the observations, $y_{n} ∈ {0, 1}$ are their true labels

I'm trying to see what is the condition for which there exists a unique solution for logistic regression.

I tried the following based on the minimal machine learning knowledge I have.

I estimate the gradient of log-likelihood function with respect to W.
which is :

$\sum_{n = 1}^{N}y_{n}x_{n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sigma(w^Tx_n)x_n$

Similarly, I found the Hessain.

$ - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \sigma(w^Tx_n).(1 - \sigma(w^Tx_n))x_n.x^T_n$

So, to have a unique maximizer I believe that $x_n.x^T_n$ should be PSD.

I'm not sure whether I'm correct here. Please, can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12492/when-does-a-logistic-regression-model-have-a-unique-solution) will help

Comment: Thank you very much :)